# In ActiveAdmin, Collections are not (re)loaded in filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've created a User model.

In #index I want to be able to filter those fields (position, company, town) by selecting available values but it seems the User.all retrieve always the same set of records even if I add new users:

```
filter :id
filter :gender, :as => :select, :collection => Interlocutor::GENDERS
filter :last_name
filter :first_name
filter :email
filter :phone
filter :position, :as => :select, :collection => User.all.map(&:position)
filter :company, :as => :select, :collection => User.all.map(&:company)
filter :zipcode
filter :town, :as => :select, :collection => User.all.map(&:town)
filter :created_at
filter :updated_at
```

I must restart the server to make it work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to override default behavior. In the controller:

```
before_filter :use_dynamic_filter, :only => :index

def use_dynamic_filter
  self.class.reset_filters!
  self.class.filter :your_filter_defs_here, :as => :select, :collection => User.all
end
```

Thanks to Drew Ulmer.